# How to show that Poisson sum of iid $X_i\sim$ Rademacher r.v.'s converges to $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I have a random sum of independent random variables, i.e. $S_N=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_N$, where $$P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=0.5$$ which I think would make $X_i$ belong to a [Rademacher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution). If $N\sim \mathrm{Po}(\lambda)$ and is independent, how can I show that $$\frac{S_N}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$$ as $\lambda$ goes to infinity?

Comment: You do not need the $S_N$ to be iid but the $X_i$ to be iid.

Comment: Did you try to compute the characteristic function of $S_N/\sqrt{\lambda}$?

Comment: @Did Yes, but I get caught in the Cos(z) , the CF of Rademacher, and can never get it to converge to N(0,1).

Comment: Which function did you get?

Comment: @Did I got $\varphi_{\frac{S_N}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}=...=e^{\lambda(e^{i*cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}})}-1)}$, does this converge to $N(0,1)$ as $\lambda$ goes to inf?

Comment: Actually, $\varphi_\lambda(t)=\exp(\lambda(\cos(t/\sqrt{\lambda})-1))$. Now, fix $t$ and look for the pointwise limit of $\varphi_\lambda(t)$ when $\lambda\to\infty$. First step: what is the behaviour of $\cos(t/\sqrt{\lambda})$?

Comment: @Did Is it that $cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}})=1$ as $\lambda$ goes to infinity? But then what happens to the $t$?

Comment: The limit $1$ is true but too imprecise. What would be a simple equivalent of $\cos(t/\sqrt{\lambda})-1$?

Comment: Is it $-1+\sum_{k=0}^{inf}\frac{(-1)^k(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}})^{2k}}{(2k)!}$ ?

Comment: Are you able to show the crucial step $$\varphi_{S_N/\sqrt\lambda}(z) = g_N(\varphi_X(z/\sqrt\lambda))$$ of the answer you accepted?

Comment: @Did Yes, I believe so, since the RV's $X_i$ are IID and independent of $N$ would allow me to make use of it

Comment: "Believe"? How is any belief involved? Either you can or you cannot, and your last comment, pretty evasive, contains nothing showing that you can.

Comment: @Did Ok, does this work? $\varphi_{\frac{S_N}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}(z)=E[exp (iz(\frac{S_N}{\sqrt{\lambda}}+0)]=exp(iz\cdot0)\cdot E[exp(i(\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}})S_N)]=1\cdot E[exp(i(\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}})S_N)]=E[E[exp(i(\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}})S_N)]|N]]=\{Doob-Dynkin\}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E[exp(i\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}S_N)|N=n]P(N=n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E[exp(i\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}S_n)]P(N=n)=\{Independence\}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E[exp(i\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}(X_1+...+X_n))]P(N=n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\varphi_X(\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}))^nP(N=n)=g_N(\varphi_X(\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}))$

Comment: The three first steps are useless and the identity $E(\exp(itS_N)\mid N=n)=E(\exp(itS_n))$ should be justified carefully but yes, this is the way to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the characteristic function of the standard normal distribution:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{izx}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 x^2}\,\mathsf dx = e^{-\frac12 z^2}. $$
Now, the characteristic function of $X_1$ is $$\varphi_X(z) = \frac12\left(e^{iz} +e^{-iz}\right) = \cos z,$$
and the generating function of $N$ is $$g_N(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda} = e^{\lambda(z-1)}. $$
Hence the characteristic function of $S_N/\sqrt\lambda$ is 
\begin{align}
\varphi_{S_N/\sqrt\lambda}(z) &= g_N(\varphi_X(z/\sqrt\lambda))\tag1\\
&= g_N(\cos(z/\sqrt\lambda))\\
&= \exp\left(\lambda\left(\cos(z/\sqrt\lambda)-1\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\lambda\left(1-\frac12\frac{z^2}\lambda + O\left(\frac{z^4}{\lambda^2}\right)-1 \right) \right)\\
&\stackrel{\lambda\to\infty}\longrightarrow \exp\left(-\frac12 z^2\right).
\end{align}

To justify $(1)$, we have
$$
\varphi_{S_N/\sqrt\lambda}(z) = \mathbb E\left[e^{iz\left(S_N/\sqrt{\lambda}\right)} \right]
= \mathbb E\left[ e^{i\left(z/\sqrt\lambda\right)S_n}\right]
=\varphi_{S_N}\left(z/\sqrt\lambda\right)
$$
and for any $\theta\in\mathbb C$, 
\begin{align}
\varphi_{S_N}(\theta) &= \mathbb E\left[ e^{i\theta S_N}\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[ \mathbb E\left[ e^{i\theta S_N} \mid N\right]\right]\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb E\left[ e^{i\theta S_N} \mid N=n\right]\mathbb P(N=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb E\left[e^{i\theta S_n} \right]\mathbb P(N=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^n \mathbb E\left[e^{i\theta X_k} \right]\mathbb P(N=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb E\left[e^{i\theta X_1} \right]^n\mathbb P(N=n)\\
&= g_N\left(\mathbb E\left[e^{i\theta X_1}\right]\right)\\
&= g_N\left(\varphi_X(\theta)\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Two points to modify. First, $\varphi_N(z)=\exp(\lambda(e^{iz}-1))$, not $\varphi_N(z)=\exp(\lambda(iz-1))$. Second, if the $\varphi$s are really characteristic functions, then $\varphi_{S_N/\sqrt\lambda}(z) \ne \varphi_N(\varphi_X(z/\sqrt\lambda))$, rather $\varphi_{S_N/\sqrt\lambda}(z) \ne g_N(\varphi_X(z/\sqrt\lambda))$ where $g_N(s)=E(s^N)$ is the generating function of $N$, not its characteristic function. Correcting all this should bring you back to the formulas in my comments on main (and explain the "mystery" of your factor $i$...).

Comment: Are you able to show the crucial step $$\varphi_{S_N/\sqrt\lambda}(z) = g_N(\varphi_X(z/\sqrt\lambda))\ ?$$